# Make duplicate string then join two strings together in a table

Tags: list-manipulation

I have two lists of `data`, `dataA` and `dataB`.

```
dataA = {100169}
dataB = {0001,Olivine,Process},{0002,Olivine,Process},{0003,Olivine,Process}
```

I don't know how to write a function that would give me a data table that looks like this.

```
{100169,0001,Olivine,Process}
{100169,0002,Olivine,Process}
{100169,0003,Olivine,Process}
```

Comment: Use `ArrayPad` or `ArrayFlatten`.

Comment: Or `Join[dataA,#]&/@dataB`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just `Prepend` the element of `dataA` to each of the elements of `dataB`:

```
dataA = {100169};
dataB = {{0001, Olivine, Process}, {0002, Olivine, Process}, {0003, Olivine, Process}}
Prepend[#, First[dataA]] & /@ dataB
```